# vb axwindowsmediaplayer how to display controler like next, pause , play when full screen

Tags: vb.net, axwindowsmediaplayer

i create vb AxWindowsMediaPlayer1 and i remove window player `CONTROLLER` `AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode=none)`and i
  want  when my program full screen and mouse move down display my `CONTROLLER` what i can do.? thanks `Visual Vincent` 
[image: example of controller]

Comment: Make a custom fullscreen mode. Instead of setting the media player to be fullscreen, just maximize your form and make it borderless.

Comment: thanks for reply.. please i dont know how to start to do this can you help me. or can you send link to me where i can read and solve my problem

Comment: [**`Form.WindowState`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate(v=vs.110).aspx), [**`Form.FormBorderStyle`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) + [**values**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: so thanks best its work  `*****` to you

Comment: I'll take that as a positive reply, but why the `*****`?

Comment: in coment no place to vote +, if existed ili give you but does not exist you help me,  i give you 5 star so thank

Comment: oooh i cnt see it but iready gve you thnks best

Comment: Oh you meant it as 5 stars... Glad I could help! Good luck! :)

Comment: tnks Visual Vincent

Comment: hii `visual vincent` its possible to make controler hide after `mouse stoped ` and show after `mouse move ` ?

Comment: Yes, but it is a bit more complicated approach. What you could do is start a [**`Timer`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) in the end of each `MouseMove` and stop it in the beginning. After a certain Interval the `Timer` will tick and hide the controls.

Comment: thks visual vincent let me try

Comment: hii `visual vincent` thanks for every thing , i finish full screen to display controler i use timer and i make border less into timer and idle,date and time to check mouse moved, so thnks for you help.. but how to make vb axwindow media player to be real program means be executable(`setup`) like vlc that run to any computer please best can you help me thanks..

Comment: Glad to hear that! -- The .exe itself will run on any computer as long as you ship the needed dependencies with it (dll-files, for example). If you want to put this into an installer then you should look into [**Installer projects**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects) for Visual Studio 2015, or [**this**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.100).aspx) if you're using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: tnanks best for your help so thanks visual vincent

Comment: My pleasure, good luck!